# Insert a page definition in the right order

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table `SlideList` that defines all available slides that can be put into a PowerPoint presentation. I have a table `ReportList` that defines which slides go into a presentation for a company and the order they're to be inserted.

I've been maintaining `ReportList` by hand (yes, that's a nightmare and needs to be fixed, but it's not the point of this post), so upon initial creation of a report, I've left gaps of 10 in the `SlideOrder` so it's easy to insert additional slides without having to renumber everything by hand.

I've written the following T-SQL to identify the `SlideOrder` value to use when inserting a new slide immediately after an existing slide for every report that has that slide in it.

For example: I have existing slide `Foo`, and I've created a new slide `Bar`. I need to insert `Bar` as the next slide after `Foo` in every report that contains `Foo`. Some reports may have `Foo` as slide #50, others as slide #302 - this code will figure that out, split the gap to the *next* slide, and return that value as the `SlideOrder` for `Bar`. If there is *no* gap (`Foo` is `SlideOrder` #50, and `Baz` exists at `SlideOrder` #51) it will simply print a message and I'll have to adjust that one by hand.

Here is my T-SQL code. While it's functional, I'm looking for improvements to this code and to learn more T-SQL. If you're feeling really generous and want to rewrite it to update all the `SlideOrder` values > `Foo` so that `Baz` can be inserted and there are no gaps in `SlideOrder`, go for it! I'll be very grateful, but that's not what I'm after at the moment. (Note that this code simply prints out the `SlideOrder` of `Foo`, the `SlideOrder` that `Bar` will go in, and the `SlideOrder` of what follows - it doesn't do the actual insert.)

```
USE DevDB
GO 

DECLARE @SlideToFollow as nvarchar(300)
SELECT @SlideToFollow = 'Foo'

DECLARE @SlideToFollowID as int
SELECT @SlideToFollowID = SlideID
  FROM ReportList RL inner join SlideList SL on RL.SlideID = SL.ID
 WHERE SlideName = @SlideToFollow

DECLARE @CurrentClinicID as int
SELECT @CurrentClinicID = min(ClinicID)
  FROM ReportList
 WHERE SlideID = @SlideToFollowID

WHILE @CurrentClinicID is not null
BEGIN
  DECLARE @Slide1QOrder as int
  SELECT @Slide1QOrder = SlideOrder
    FROM ReportList
   WHERE SlideID = @SlideToFollowID
     and ClinicID = @CurrentClinicID

  DECLARE @NextSlideOrder as int
  SELECT @NextSlideOrder = min(SlideOrder)
    FROM ReportList
   WHERE ClinicID = @CurrentClinicID 
     AND SlideOrder > @Slide1QOrder


  IF @NextSlideOrder = @Slide1QOrder + 1 
    PRINT N'ClinicID: ' + Cast(@currentClinicID as nvarchar) + ' does not have room to insert a new slide after order: ' + cast(@Slide1QOrder as nvarchar);
  ELSE
  BEGIN
    DECLARE @NewSlideOrder as int
    SELECT @NewSlideOrder = @Slide1QOrder + (@NextSlideOrder - @Slide1QOrder)/2
    PRINT N'ClinicID: ' + Cast(@CurrentClinicID as nvarchar) + '  ' + @SlideToFollow + ' slide order: ' + Cast(@Slide1QOrder as nvarchar) + ' New Slide Order: ' + Cast(@NewSlideOrder as nvarchar) + '  Next Slide Order: ' + Cast(@NextSlideOrder as nvarchar);
  END

  SELECT @CurrentClinicID = min(ClinicID)
    FROM ReportList
   WHERE SlideID = @SlideToFollowID
     AND ClinicID > @CurrentClinicID
END
```

SlideList:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SlideList](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SlideName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [SlideDesc] [nvarchar](255) NULL,
    [ExcelWksht] [nvarchar](255) NULL
GO
```

ReportList:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ReportList](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ClinicID] [int] NULL,
    [SlideID] [int] NULL,
    [SlideOrder] [int] NULL
GO
```

Comment: One thing I just discovered - I should probably be using `SET @Local = (SELECT...)` instead of just `SELECT @Local = ...`

Comment: So confusing.  I bet row_number() could be your friend.  Or a recursive CTE.     You should post a better explanation of what you need to do with some data and desired output on dba.stackexchange

Comment: @paparazzo - can you be a bit more explicit? What's confusing you? In what way would `Row_number` be my friend?

Comment: Follow my suggestion to post on dba or not.

Comment: Ah. Somehow, your edit hadn't appeared when I posted my response. If I don't get satisfaction here in the next couple of days, I'll certainly move to [DBA.SE]